# Apache Flink: how to use SourceFunction to execute a task at specified interval?

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming, flink-cep

I need my flink job to pull records from a database at specified interval and archive it after processing. I have implemented SourceFunction to fetch the required records from database and added the SourceFunction as the source for StreamExecutionEnvironment. How can i specify that the StreamExecutionEnvironment needs to fetch records from database by using the SourceFunction every 10 minutes?

SourceFunction:

```
public class MongoDBSourceFunction implements SourceFunction<List<Book>>{

    public void cancel() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    public void run(org.apache.flink.streaming.api.functions.source.SourceFunction.SourceContext
<List<Book>> context) throws Exception {

        List<Book> books = getBooks();

        context.collect(books);

    }

    public List<Book> getBooks() {
        List<Book> books = new ArrayList<Book>();

        //fetch all books from database     
        return books;
    }

}
```

Processor:

```
import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.environment.StreamExecutionEnvironment;

public class ArchiveJob {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        final StreamExecutionEnvironment env = 
    StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment();

        env.addSource(new MongoDBSourceFunction()).print();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add this functionality to the `MongoDBSourceFunction` itself. For example, you could instantiate a `ScheduledExecutorService` in the `open` method and schedule the read task using this executor.

Note, that it is important to hold the checkpointing lock while emitting records.

Comment: The [SourceFunction for Apache NiFi flink connector](https://github.com/apache/flink/blob/master/flink-connectors/flink-connector-nifi/src/main/java/org/apache/flink/streaming/connectors/nifi/NiFiSource.java) uses `Thread.sleep()`. Is this acceptable or using `ScheduledExecutorService ` the only way to go?

Comment: `Thread.sleep()` should also work if you make sure that you release the checkpoint lock while sleeping.

Comment: I am not using any checkpointing. I am simply querying the database every 15 minutes and emit those records. where does the checkpointing lock comes into picture?

Comment: It is important to emit records under the checkpoint lock if you want to use checkpointing, because otherwise the state is not consistent.